# In which file/place does GNOME store the translations for other languages?

Tags: gnome, gui

I am somewhat uneducated about localization in DE, since I prefere the English original for texts anyway. However I installed a GNOME DE for some persons onlys speaking German. I could set the GNOME/display language to German and basically enjoy `Datei` in place of `file` everywhere (as by magic).

The problem is that at one tiny place (the power setting/battery indicator) it says *"Not charging"* leaving a spot of imperfection, as it should be more accurately in German something like "*Nicht ladend*".

Now I did a :

```
 grep -iIr 'Not charging' /usr
```

hoping it would find me the place where the translations/translated labels reside. Unfortunatelly it does not yield any results.

Where are those localization translation files that GNOME uses to provide a German UI?

It is somewhat hard to consult a documentation, since a websearch regarding `Gnome translation files localization` is more likely to show guides how to engage in doing part of the development and become a translator, but does not indicate where the files or data eventually is stored

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The translation files are stored, in compiled form (`.mo`), under `/usr/share/locale`. Those for German are in `/usr/share/locale/de/LC_MESSAGES`.

These files aren’t intended to be modified directly. You can decompile and recompile them using `gettext`’s `msgunfmt` and `msgfmt` tools. Even better, if you download the source for whichever GNOME component is missing your message, edit the corresponding `.po` file, and rebuild the `.mo` file, you’ll then also be able to submit a patch and perhaps have your translation included in future releases...